# Debug message in discord.js with handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to make a discord.js debugger that prints all message from a server. I've tried this but it does not work. Here's my code:

```js
module.export = (client) => {
  client.on('messageCreate', (m) => {
    console.log(`${m.content}`)
  )};
};
```

I use handlers from Under Ctrl: https://github.com/notunderctrl/discordjs-v14-series

Could you help me to revise the code / tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: I don't think anyone could help you without seeing more of your code. Where do you import this?

Comment: No, this is my full code, i add this at greeting.js and i make a new folders inside event folders, i wish i can show you, do you have discord by any chance?

Comment: Make sure you have toggled on your app's message intent otherwise it will not be able to read message content.

Answer (score 0):

```
function log_m_content(client) {
    client.on("messageCreate"), m => {
        console.log(m.content);
    };
};

module.exports = {
    log_m_content:log_m_content
};
```

This exports the function you wanna use example:

```
const log = require("./examplename.js")
log.log_m_content(YOURCLIENT);
```